# Mask file name on redirect

Tags: python, redirect, flask

I have a static html page in my application stored at `static/foo/bar/index.html`. I would like to server this page to `/my-url/`. In Flask, my routing looks like this:

```
@app.route('/my-url/')
def myurl():
  return redirect(url_for('static', filename='foo/bar/index.html'))
```

Using this routing, my static html file appears at:

```
localhost:8000/my-url/index.html
```

I would like the final url to be at:

```
localhost:8000/my-url/
```

How can I get Flask to mask the index.html file name in the final url?

Comment: The final URL would be `localhost:8000/static/foo/bar/index.html`, as you are redirecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of redirecting, serve the file directly yourself, using the [`flask.send_from_directory()` function](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/api/#flask.send_from_directory):

```
from flask import send_from_directory

@app.route('/my-url/')
def myurl():
    return send_from_directory(app.static_folder, 'foo/bar/index.html')
```